# What is an instance, instance class and how many instances we can have per version in google app engine project?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

How many instances we can have per version? I mean that is there any limit for instances for a version, if so, what is the limit??

Comment: It's unclear whether you're asking about free or paid app engine instances, or even whether you're looking at the standard or flexible environment. In all cases, this may be a good place to start: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/an-overview-of-app-engine

Answer (score 0):

The full outline of App Engine instance handling is available at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/how-instances-are-managed

You can have as many or as few instances as you want for any version. If left to autoscale you can have an infinite number of instances should the requirement exist due to traffic.